# AWS SQS How can I reset a message's ReceiveCount

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, dead-letter

For various reasons my consumer on AWS sometimes reads a few messages from an SQS queue and decides to put some of them back in the queue to be processed later.

The way I do that is by setting their `VisibilityTimeout` to 0 which makes them immediately visible to other consumers. This is documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html#terminating-message-visibility-timeout).

The problem is that after doing that a few times, the message's `ReceiveCount` reaches the `maxReceiveCount` which causes the message to be moved to the DLQ. I'm wondering if I can somehow reset the message's `ReceiveCount` to avoid that.

The only option I can currently think of is to just send a copy of the message back to the beginning of the queue and deleting the original message.

Comment: i think something is missing with your request, can you explain why you want to push back the messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm wondering if I can somehow reset the message's ReceiveCount to avoid that.

Sadly, you **can't reset** it as you its automatically managed by SQS. You have no control over it.

If you don't want to use multiple SQS, one for different purpose and consumer, the only solution I can think of is to simply **increase** `maxReceiveCount` to account for those extra reads. So if you know that your messages will be read and returned to the queue, let say 5 times, then increase your `maxReceiveCount` to 8 for instances. This will mean that if the message is read 3 times more then expected, there is something wrong with it.

Answer (score 3):

This all depends on your workload. It's not uncommon to have a lambda on your DLQ that will write messages back into the primary queue for retry. However, you often transform the message a little and add (for instance) a key to the json packet like `dlq_retry_count`. Then your DLQ lambda can retry it if below a certain threshold or delete the message.

If you just keep taking DLQ messages and pumping them back into the queue with no means of tracking you could end up with a queue full of poison pill messages.